# Synthesis of generate blocks

Tags: synthesis

I am using RTL Compiler for Synthesis. I am using if-else statement in a for-generate block.I am instantiating same module in both if statement and else statement with different genvar condition. In net-list I am getting two different modules for if and else.

How can we get single module name for both if and else?

please help me.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to achieve this. Each generate block has it's own label which is used to create an absolute instance path.

This could only be solved if VHDL would know an else-part in the generate statement, but currently there is no such statement.

Why do you need to have equal names in the if- or in else-part?
If it's for constraint files, there are ways to used wildcards or relative paths to identify modules in a design hierarchy.